# Getting error in hilt HiltViewModel annotated class should contain exactly one @Inject annotated constructor

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

**Error:** How to resolve this, getting this wiered error even though I am not doing any inject in view model

```
/Users/user/Documents/Personal/android-in-app-review-engine/Application/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/inappreview/code/MainActivityViewModel.java:7: error: [Hilt]
public final class MainActivityViewModel extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel {
             ^
  @HiltViewModel annotated class should contain exactly one @Inject annotated constructor.
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.
```

MainActivity.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), InAppReviewView {

    @Inject
    lateinit var inAppReviewManager: InAppReviewManager

    private val viewModel : MainActivityViewModel by viewModels()

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        viewModel.setInAppReviewView(this)
        setOnClickListener()
    }

    private fun setOnClickListener() {
        binding.startReviewProcess.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.startReview()
        }
    }

    override fun showReviewFlow() {
        val dialog = InAppReviewPromptDialog()
        dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, null)
    }

}
```

**MainActivityViewModel.kt**

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainActivityViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private lateinit var inAppReviewView: InAppReviewView

    /**
     * Sets an interface that backs up the In App Review prompts.
     * */
    fun setInAppReviewView(inAppReviewView: InAppReviewView) {
        this.inAppReviewView = inAppReviewView
    }

    /**
     * Start In App Review
     * */
    fun startReview() {
        inAppReviewView.showReviewFlow()
    }

}
```

**App.kt**

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class App : Application()
```

Comment: If you remove the `@HiltViewModel` does the error go away? If you are not injecting anything then you dont need it

Comment: Yes ....  That works :) ... Please add as a answer ... I will accept it 
Its tricky if we don't know ... I always had a variable in constructor injection ... this is the first time I faced a view model without constructor injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not injecting anything remove the `@HiltViewModel`, you only need that when you want to inject something into your ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69303617/15184582). Make sure that you don't have any `@HiltViewModel` annotated view model with empty constructor